# Replace contents between headings

Tags: ms-word, docx, docx4j

So what I am trying to do is I want to fetch Heading wise data from word via docx4j and want to replace the data that is in those Headings, I do not want to change the heading text just want to remove all the things in that Heading and replace it with another. I searched everywhere for 4 days but not able to find a successful way of doing it, I can do it by fetching text line by line manually but that won't be efficient so is there any way I can directly get Heading wise data and thn can remove every child in that Heading and append another child in that same heading?

Below I have attached an image of the word document, so thing is I want to remove everything in the Heading1 i.e. "2. Functional Requirements" but I do not want to change the heading or it's heirarchy, I just want to remove everything i.e. 2.1.1 and it's subdata, 2.1, BR_1,etc and want to append data same way here as child of "2. Functional Requirements" Style - Heading1.
Below is the image of the word document:

[image]

Please Help me, any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you, have a great day.

Comment: So you need  (1) a way to find the heading, and (2) a way to find the next heading at the same level.  Re (1), do you want to find it by its number (assuming it is numbered), or words in it, or something else?  Re (2), once you have the list id and level for (1), you can look for the next match.  Note that the numPr may be in the heading style definition, rather than on the paragraph itself.

Comment: Once you've got the actual heading, you can use Word's internal \HeadingLevel bookmark to extend the range to the encompass all content related to that Heading. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/Concepts/Miscellaneous/predefined-bookmarks. You can then move the start of the range to the end of your Heading before replacing the content. There is plenty of code (especially VBA code) about to demonstrate that. Do a search for "\HeadingLevel".